# Google sign-in implementation for an enterprise app that runs both locally and in the cloud

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin, google-developers-console

I'm trying to implement Google sign-in for an ASP.Net enterprise app that can be installed locally on a Windows/Mac PC or can be hosted on the cloud.

If installed locally, when user launches the app, it runs in a web browser with the following URL:

localhost/myappname

If cloud hosted,

IP address/myappname

Since access origin can vary based on the deployment location of the app, how to specify Access origin URL and redirect URL in Google Developer console? Access-Control-Allow-Origin error will occur if the address from which the Google sign-in is initiated is not configured in the Google Developer Console.
I would like to know how Google sign-in should be implemented in such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

As it requires javascript you could integrate easily, I found the next[documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) to integrate Google Sign-In into your web app.

Here is an example of the code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I used from this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web), I think this is what you require to do.

Comment: No. I'm not looking for single sign on. I'm trying to add Microsoft and Google sign-in.

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: I know how to implement Google sign-in using Javascript. My question is regarding access origin specified in Google Developer console. When you are not sure about access origin (since it will vary between customer to customer), how to specify it in Developer Console.